# Programming a recursive formula into Mathematica and find the nth position in the sequence

Tags: programming, recursion

Well, I have the following recursive formula (where $\text{n}$ gives the position in the sequence):

$$\text{P}_\text{n}=\alpha\cdot\text{P}_{\text{n}-1}+\text{P}_{\text{n}-2}\tag1$$

For arbitrary $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

And I know that $\text{P}_1=\beta$ and $\text{P}_2=\gamma$, where $\beta\space\wedge\space\gamma\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

How can I write a program that gives me the value of the nth position in the sequence?

---

Example, find the value of the 5th position in the sequence when we know that $\beta=1$ and $\alpha=\gamma=2$. Now it has to give the value $\text{P}_5=29$.

So, I think that the code has to start with:

```
\[Alpha] =2;
\[Beta] =1;
\[Gamma] =2;
n =5;
```

Comment: [RSolveValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolveValue.html) does exactly this.

Comment: I entered 'recurrence' in the help browser and got several useful hits. So I'd say this comes down to checking documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html):

```
ClearAll[rs]
rs[α_, β_, γ_] := p /. 
  RSolve[{p[n] == α p[n - 1] + p[n - 2], p[1] == β, p[2] == γ}, p, n][[1]]

N @ rs[2, 1, 2][5]
```

> 29.

Alternatively, [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html):

```
ClearAll[rt]
rt[α_, β_, γ_][k_] := Last @ 
   RecurrenceTable[{p[n] == α p[n - 1] + p[n - 2], p[1] == β, p[2] == γ}, p,  {n, k}];

rt[2, 1, 2][5]
```

> 29

Answer (score 5):

Since you have a three-term linear difference equation, it is very straightforward to use `LinearRecurrence[]` directly:

```
With[{α = 2, β = 1, γ = 2}, 
     LinearRecurrence[{α, 1}, {β, γ}, {5}][[1]]]
   29
```

---

A more manual, but equivalent, method involves repeatedly multiplying the (Frobenius) companion matrix of your difference equation's characteristic polynomial with a vector containing your initial conditions. `MatrixPower[]`'s three-argument action form (which directly generates $\mathbf A^n\mathbf v$ as opposed to separately generating $\mathbf A^n$ before multiplying with $\mathbf v$) is particularly convenient for this:

```
With[{α = 2, β = 1, γ = 2},
     MatrixPower[{{α, 1}, {1, 0}}, 5 - 2, {γ, β}][[1]]]
   29
```

Answer (score 4):

[`RSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolveValue.html) gives an explicit expression:

```
RSolveValue[{P[n] == α P[n - 1] + P[n - 2], P[1] == β, P[2] == γ}, P[n], n] // FullSimplify
```

> $$
> \frac{2^{-n-1} \left(\left(\alpha -\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4}\right)^n \left(\alpha  \gamma -\left(\alpha ^2+2\right) \beta \right)+\left(\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4}+\alpha \right)^n
>    \left(\left(\alpha ^2+2\right) \beta -\alpha  \gamma \right)-\alpha  \sqrt{\alpha ^2+4} \beta  \left(\alpha -\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4}\right)^n-\alpha  \sqrt{\alpha ^2+4} \beta 
>    \left(\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4}+\alpha \right)^n+\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4} \gamma  \left(\alpha -\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4}\right)^n+\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4} \gamma  \left(\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4}+\alpha
>    \right)^n\right)}{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4}}
> $$

For your particular parameters:

```
With[{α = 2, β = 1, γ = 2},
  RSolveValue[{P[n] == α P[n - 1] + P[n - 2], P[1] == β, P[2] == γ}, P[5], n]]
(*    29    *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also write this almost verbatim as you stated it:

```
Clear[p]; p[n_] := p[n] = \[Alpha] p[n - 1] + p[n - 2];
p[1] = 1; p[2] = 2; \[Alpha] = 2;
```

To get the 5th term:

```
p[5]
29
```

Or leave the values unspecified to get the general form:

```
Clear[p]; p[n_] := p[n] = a p[n - 1] + p[n - 2]; p[1] = b; p[2] = g;

p[5]
b + a g + a (g + a (b + a g))
```